# How to get average of two excel column

Tags: java, apache-poi

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVsTo.png)I need some help to get the maximum value of two column average with xlsx files 
I can do that with jxl  but I am working with large excels..
thanks a lot for any answers

```
public void readExcel() throws BiffException, IOException{//method to read 
contents form excel
    String FilePath = "C:\\Users\\ok.xls";
    double max1=0;
    double max2=0;
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
    Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0);// TO get the access to the sheet
    int totalNoOfRows = sh.getRows();// To get the number of rows present in  sheet
 //   int totalNoOfCols = sh.getColumns();// To get the number of columns present in sheet

    for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
        firstarray.add(sh.getCell(18, row).getContents());
        secondarray.add(sh.getCell(17, row).getContents());
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < totalNoOfRows; row++)
    {
          if(Double.parseDouble(firstarray.get(row))>=max1 ){
            max1= Double.parseDouble(firstarray.get(row));
    }
          if(Double.parseDouble(secondarray.get(row))>=max2 ){ 
            max2= Double.parseDouble(secondarray.get(row));
      }  
}     double max=(max1 + max2)/2; 
    System.out.println(max);
    }//end of method to read contents from excel
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more in detail what you mean by *the maximum value of two column average*? Do both columns contain an average and you want to receive the larger one or do you want to calculate the average of those two columns?

Comment: You put `xlsx` in the description, but are attempting to open an `xls`, those are not the same thing, `xls` has limit of 65k rows.

Comment: I need to sum two column and get the average Like in the pic I added

Comment: Thanks Nexevis , I know its not same thing .. I just show what I have .. but I need some code that do work with xlsx file

Answer (score 2):

You could let Excel doing it by using the AVERAGE fonction in a formula you put an unused cell. Then you evaluate it and get the result.

EDIT : Here is a code snippet.

```
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("S1"); // Choose an unused cell here
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

// Formula that gets average of Q column and R columns' maximums
cell.setCellFormula("AVERAGE(MAX(Q:Q);MAX(R:R))");

// Let Excel do the math
CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , can You show me haw I can do that with code java

Comment: I put an untested code example in my edit. See the documentation about formula evaluation for more information : https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll try this .

Comment: that solution worked .. it sets max value in new cell .. but when I tried to evaluate the cell value it throws me this error : org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFFormulaEvaluator$RowFlushedException: Row 0 has been flushed, cannot evaluate all cells

Comment: I'm not a POI expert, but have you flushed anything to file before doing your average calculation ? This is what the exception suggests.

Comment: My file was converted from csv to excel and then I did what you suggested .. I think thats why ?

Comment: Does your file happens to be a XSLX file ? The "Formula Evaluation and SXSSF" part of the documentation I linked to could explain your error.

Comment: What is your version of POI ?